# How to combine many csv files into a large csv without holding the whole object in RAM

Tags: r

I am working on combining csv files into one large csv file that will not be able to fit into my machine's RAM. Is there anyway to go about doing that in R? I realize that I could load each individual csv file into R and append the file to an existing database table but for quirky reasons I'm looking to end up with a large csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create 3 test files and then create a variable `Files` containing their names.  We used `Sys.glob` to do get the vector of file names but you may need to modify this statement. Then define `outFile` as the name of the output file.  For each component of `Files` read in the file with that name and write it out.  If it is the first file then write it all out and if it is a subsequent file write it all except for the header being sure to use `append = TRUE`.  Note that `L` is overwritten each time a file is read in so that only one file takes up space at a time.

```
# create test files using built in data frame BOD
write.csv(BOD, "BOD1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(BOD, "BOD2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(BOD, "BOD3.csv", row.names = FALSE)

Files <- Sys.glob("BOD*.csv") # modify as appropriate
outFile <- "out.csv"

for(f in Files) { 
  L <- readLines(f)
  if (f == Files[1]) cat(L, file = outFile, sep = "\n") 
  else cat(L[-1], file = outFile, sep = "\n", append = TRUE)
}

# check that the output file was written properly
file.show(outFile)
```

The loop could alternately be replaced with this:

```
for(f in Files) { 
  d <- read.csv(f)
  first <- f == Files[1]
  write.table(d, outFile, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = first, append = !first)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to read each csv file one by one and write out with `write.table` and option `append = T`.

Something like this:

1. read one csv file;
2. `write.table(..., append = T)` to the final csv file;
3. remove the table with `rm()`;
4. `gc()`.

Repeate until all files are written out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `append = TRUE`

```
first <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c(10,20))
second <- data.frame(c(3,4), c(30,40))
write.table(first, "file.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE)
write.table(second, "file.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```